# SQL multiple joins not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this:

```
SELECT user_games.APPID, games_steam.name, games_xbox.name
FROM user_games
JOIN games_steam ON user_games.APPID = games_steam.APPID
JOIN games_xbox ON user_games.APPID = games_xbox.APPID
WHERE user_games.UID = "76561197996836099"
GROUP BY user_games.APPID
```

But it does not return anything, But if I remove either join and its corresponding SELECT they both work fine. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Maybe because there is no record in one of the joined tables for the APPID returned when quering UID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rows being returned must meet *all* conditions of the query

- If you take only the first JOIN, you will get all rows where the `APPID` matches `user_games` to `games_steam`
- If you take only the second JOIN, you will get all rows where the `APPID` matches `user_games` to `games_xbox`
- However, if you include *both* JOINs, you will get only rows where the `APPID` matches `user_games` to both `games_steam` *and* `games_xbox`. While there may be such rows, it is by no means guaranteed by the existence of rows in the previous two queries.

The simplistic solution is to convert both `JOIN`s to `LEFT JOIN`s (strictly, converting `INNER JOIN`s to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s, but `INNER` and `OUTER` are optional keywords). This has the result that *no rows will be filtered out*, but your results will contain the following:

- Rows where `APPID` matches both `games_steam` *and* `games_xbox`, with details from both matches
- Rows where `APPID` matches `games_steam`, with the details from `games_xbox` all `NULL`
- Rows where `APPID` matches `games_xbox`, with the details from `games_steam` all `NULL`
- Rows where `APPID` matches *neither* table, with the details from `games_steam` *and* `games_xbox` all `NULL`

You can of course eliminate any one of those cases with an appropriate `WHERE` clause, e.g. `WHERE ... AND (games_steam.APPID IS NOT NULL OR games_xbox.APPID IS NOT NULL)`.

However, you may also want to consider whether this is actually how you want the results to be combined - i.e. with the different joins adding columns, rather than running the two separate queries and having them add rows.

Comment: How would I go about combining the results, As I want to get the Names from Games_steam and games_xbox to for where the APPIDs match in user_games. As you said, I get - | APPID | Name | Name | - right now.

Comment: How do you want them combined? i.e. What would you like the result to look like?

Comment: Just two two Name columns combined into one.

Comment: You could use `COALESCE(games_steam.name, games_xbox.name)` - but only if you know for sure that a single `APPID` cannot appear in both `games_steam` and `games_xbox`. Otherwise, you could just write out both join queries separately, and combine them with `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL says it can give indeterminate results if you select columns that are not aggregated and not in GROUP BY columns. [Read here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Comment: This does not answer the question as such, and should instead be a comment.

Comment: Also, it doesn't just say that, it's a fundamental fact of SQL's `GROUP BY` statement; MySQL is very unusual in allowing you to write such queries at all.